# Deceptively Easy: Pairwise Coprime Tuple Counting

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, gcd-and-lcm

> Suppose I have $M_1,...,M_n$ prime numbers in a specific range $[M_\min,M_\max]$ such that $M_i-1$ is not odd-squarefree ($\exists p^2|M_i-1, p$ odd). Let $n_i=\frac{M_i-1}{2}$. Find all the r-tuples of $n_i$'s such that $(n_{j_1},...,n_{j_r})$ are pairwise coprime. We can assume $r<9$.

**Remarks:** The brute force method is to simply enumerate all r-tuples and check each one in $O(n^8)$ at worst. I can see that the problem can be reduced in the following way: construct a graph between $n_i,n_j$ iff $\gcd(n_i,n_j)=1$, the problem is to enumerate all cliques of size r. Is there a better way? I also thought of partitioning the set by classes where class $i$ contains the elements whose smallest prime divisor is the $i$-th prime number $p_i$ but this won't affect the complexity...

Comment: Where does the problem come from, or how did it arise?

Comment: @BillDubuque It emerged from counting combined linear congruential generators with their associated prime numbers ranging in a specific interval.

Comment: You may get more pertinent answers if you add the details of that context to your question (which will also help other who may later search in that context).

Comment: @BillDubuque I made the reduction immediately to this problem and did not include it because I thought it would not add anything of value to the question, perhaps I could add an edit though